# Shading problem at loop-cut with subsurf and smooth shading

Tags: modeling, objects

Hello Blender Pro's :)

I am pretty new to Blender and I got a problem here that I can't solve alone. I searched google for shading problems with smooth shading and subsurf.

I already <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals. Still no difference.

The shading problems are a at a loop cut.

*I am using subsurf and solidify modifiers.*

Thank you :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: screenshot added :)

Comment: I think you shouldn't use crease on the left part of the loopcut (2nd screenshot) as it will create you areas like that (and I don't really get what are you trying to achieve by that). You can leave crease on other edges though. Also make sure that there aren't any inside faces in the mesh.

Comment: I removed the crease. But i saw that there was another loop of edges directly in the same spot as the mentioned loopcut. Any method to remove them quickly?

Comment: Use "Remove doubles". It's in the toolbox to the left.

Comment: ...Or select it (if it can't be selected separately, then really use `Remove Doubles`), click `X` and select `Edge loops`

Comment: This could be caused by interior faces as well

Comment: @Gunslinger I think your comment is due to be converted to an answer.